# sqoop GENERIC_JDBC_CONNECTOR_0024

Tags: mysql, sqoop

```
sqoop:000> start job -n mysql_to_hdfs_job
```

Exception:

```
Exception has occurred during processing command 
Exception: org.apache.sqoop.common.SqoopException Message: GENERIC_JDBC_CONNECTOR_0024:Multiple tables of the same name in different schema/catalog - For search (null, Schema1, table1) we found the table in catalogs [Schema1, Schema2, Schema3] and schemas []
Stack trace:
     at  org.apache.sqoop.client.request.ResourceRequest (ResourceRequest.java:137)  
     at  org.apache.sqoop.client.request.ResourceRequest (ResourceRequest.java:187)  
     at  org.apache.sqoop.client.request.JobResourceRequest (JobResourceRequest.java:113)  
     at  org.apache.sqoop.client.request.SqoopResourceRequests (SqoopResourceRequests.java:170)  
     at  org.apache.sqoop.client.SqoopClient (SqoopClient.java:477)  
     at  org.apache.sqoop.shell.StartJobFunction (StartJobFunction.java:64)  
     at  org.apache.sqoop.shell.SqoopFunction (SqoopFunction.java:51)  
     at  org.apache.sqoop.shell.SqoopCommand (SqoopCommand.java:134)  
     at  org.apache.sqoop.shell.SqoopCommand (SqoopCommand.java:110)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Command$execute (null:-1)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray (CallSiteArray.java:45)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Command$execute (null:-1)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell (Shell.groovy:101)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh (Groovysh.groovy:-1)  
     at  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34 (null:-1)  
     at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
     at  java.lang.reflect.Method (Method.java:498)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod (CachedMethod.java:90)  
     at  groovy.lang.MetaMethod (MetaMethod.java:324)  
     at  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl (MetaClassImpl.java:1208)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter (ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh (Groovysh.groovy:254)  
     at  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33 (null:-1)  
     at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
     at  java.lang.reflect.Method (Method.java:498)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce (PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite (PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite (AbstractCallSite.java:161)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh (Groovysh.groovy:153)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell (Shell.groovy:119)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell$leftShift$0 (null:-1)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner (ShellRunner.groovy:94)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner (InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:-1)  
     at  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23 (null:-1)  
     at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
     at  java.lang.reflect.Method (Method.java:498)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod (CachedMethod.java:90)  
     at  groovy.lang.MetaMethod (MetaMethod.java:324)  
     at  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl (MetaClassImpl.java:1208)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter (ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter (ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner (InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:123)  
     at  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22 (null:-1)  
     at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
     at  java.lang.reflect.Method (Method.java:498)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce (PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite (PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite (AbstractCallSite.java:153)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner (ShellRunner.groovy:58)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner (InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:-1)  
     at  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)  
     at  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
     at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
     at  java.lang.reflect.Method (Method.java:498)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod (CachedMethod.java:90)  
     at  groovy.lang.MetaMethod (MetaMethod.java:324)  
     at  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl (MetaClassImpl.java:1208)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter (ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter (ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner (InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:82)  
     at  java_lang_Runnable$run (null:-1)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray (CallSiteArray.java:45)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite (AbstractCallSite.java:108)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite (AbstractCallSite.java:112)  
     at  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh (Groovysh.groovy:585)  
     at  org.apache.sqoop.shell.SqoopShell (SqoopShell.java:156)
```

Comment: Try to specify schema explicitly somewhere `Multiple tables of the same name in different schema/catalog - For search (null, Schema1, table1) we found the table in catalogs [Schema1, Schema2, Schema3] and schemas []
Stack trace: `